# Solution of systems of equations with increasing funcitons

Tags: systems-of-equations

For functions $f,g: I \to \mathbb{R}$ increasing on interval $I$, prove that for the solution of the system of equations
$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{align}
   f(x_{1}) &= g(x_{2}) \\
   f(x_{2}) &= g(x_{3}) \\
   &\;\;\vdots \notag \\
   f(x_{n}) &= g(x_{1})
\end{align}
\end{cases}
$$
 $x_1 = x_2 = · · · = x_n$ is true.

I believe there might be a lemma for this, unfortunately, I can't find anything. Is there an elementary way to prove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $x_2\ge x_1$. Then $f(x_2)\ge f(x_1)$. Hence $g(x_3)\ge g(x_2)$, whence $x_3\ge x_2$. Hence $x_4\ge x_3$, and so on: $x_n\ge x_{n-1}$ and $x_1\ge x_n$, but that implies $x_1=x_2-...=x_n$.

Now suppose $x_2\le x_1$. Then similarly $x_3\le x_2$,..., $x_n\le x_{n-1}$ and $x_1\le x_n$, so again $x_1=x_2=...=x_n$.

Answer (score 2):

Well, assume WLOG (the other cases are similar) that $x_n \ge x_{n-1} \ge \dots \ge x_2 \ge x_1$, because $f$ is increasing, we get
$$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ f(x_n) \ge f(x_{n-1}) \ge \dots \ge f(x_2) \ge f(x_1)$$
$$\implies g(x_1) \ge g(x_{n}) \ge \dots \ge g(x_3) \ge g(x_2)$$
But since $g$ is also increasing, we have
$$g(x_n) \ge \dots \ge g(x_3) \ge g(x_2) \ge g(x_1)$$
This naturally means 
$$g(x_n) = \dots = g(x_3) = g(x_2) = g(x_1)$$
and thus (increasing means injective)
$$x_n=x_{n-1}=\dots=x_2=x_1$$

Comment: This answer is wrong. We cannot assume that "WLOG".

Comment: There is a problem with generalizing. Try to do it with $n=4$ but different inequalities at the start. It just doesn't work out that way, the equations aren't that kind of cyclic.

Comment: @user158834 yea I just realized this now, but didn't it kind of inspire your answer? :D
I mean, that would've been the second thing I'd think of if I realized there was a mistake in my solution.

Comment: @AnasA.Ibrahim: I did not need inspiration. It is a very old problem and I happened to know a solution.

Comment: @user158834 oh, alright good job!